# Supported Encryption Operators/Functions

Tags: formula, platform-encryption, shield-encryption

I have been looking into supported operators and functions within Salesforce, and found this list: 
Supported Operators, Functions, and Actions
Supported operators and functions:

- & and + (concatenate)
- BLANKVALUE
- CASE
- HYPERLINK
- IF
- IMAGE
- ISBLANK
- ISNULL
- NULLVALUE

Also supported:

- Spanning
- Quick Actions

Formulas can return data only in text, date, or date/time formats.

Found here:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_formulas.htm&type=5

**I see IF on there, Would IF only work with those other operators in the list? And not LEFT/MID/ISPICKVAL/ETC?  Any information you can provide will be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would IF only work with those other operators in the list?

Yes, or functions that don't directly consume an encrypted value. The example given with `&` is illustrative:

> This doesn’t work:
>   `LOWER(encryptedField__c & encryptedField__c)`
>
> Why it doesn’t work:  `LOWER` isn’t a supported function, and the input is an encrypted value.

You can use other functions only if their inputs are not encrypted values, such as Booleans produced by other, supported, formula functions. You cannot nest unsupported functions within supported functions if those unsupported functions are directly being applied to encrypted fields.

Compare the combination also depicted:

> This works:
>   `OR(ISBLANK(encryptedField__c), ISNULL(encryptedField__c))`
>
> Why it works:
>   Both ISBLANK and ISNULL are supported. OR works in this example because ISBLANK and ISNULL return a Boolean value, not an encrypted value.

Comment: Thanks David!  Appreciate the clarity very much.